# Connect Xaf Blazor to Mysql

Tags: c#, blazor, devexpress, xaf

How can I connect my Xaf Blazor application to MySQL using version 22.2.3?

Where should I precisely declare the provider when trying to change the connection string in my Xaf Blazor application? I have imported "mysql.data" and "mysql.connector", but I'm unsure where exactly it needs to be mentioned in which file.

Answer (score 0):

Start your connectionstring with:
XpoProvider=MySql;

like:
XpoProvider=MySql;Server=MyServerAddress;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;Database=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info= true;Charset=utf8

See the docs: https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/403639/devexpress-data-library/data-sources/use-the-sql-data-source/connection-strings-for-xpo-providers